# Unreal Engine 5 Assertion Failed

Tags: unreal-engine5

Im New to Unreal and i was starting my first project. when i clicked create i got this error:

```
Assertion failed: InAllocationAlignment <= PoolAlignment [File:D:\build\++UE5\Sync\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12PoolAllocator.cpp] [Line: 275]

UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_RenderCore
UnrealEditor_RenderCore
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_RHI
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
kernel32
ntdll
```

im new and dont know anything, so can anybody help?

Edit: Forgot to mention, im on windows 10, 8GB ram

Comment: Seems like there has been an issue in the DirectX12 abstraction layer, which caused the crash. What did you try to create? Did this happen while creating a project through the (epic games) launcher? Did you try to create an asset while using the Unreal Editor?

Comment: sorry for the late response, i was trying to create a blank game through unreal engine. it was my first time using unreal.

Comment: It could be an issue related to the driver version, since there are currently major efforts in the engine to move towards the most recent API of DirectX. I'd recommend a driver update to see if this fixes the crash. Also make sure to update the engine to 5.0.2 which has just been release the last couple of days.

Comment: I am wiritng this comment after reinstalling the engine and drivers, it still does not work.... I cannot post a question on the unreal engine forum because im a new user. how can i learn the engine if i cannot even open a project?

Comment: I can feel your frustration. Unfortunately based on the error message, there is not much to interpret. If you feel adventurous, I'd recommend [installing debugging symbols](https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/what-are-the-editor-symbols-for-debugging/350039/7?u=blurryroots) and try to start the project with a debugger attached, to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

thing that worked for me on ue 5.1 with dx11 was using cmd to run ue by this command

```
\your\path\to\UE_5.1\Engine\Binaries\Win64 > start UnrealEditor.exe -dx11
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a nvidia driver issue with using directx12 (which UE5 does by default).
Try running UE5 Editor with appended -dx11 on the comandline to see if you get rid of this error or extend -log to see all the startup in a new logfile for debugging (or use LOG=filename.log to log into separate file).
With my NVidia GTX Series I can't use any dx12 rendering in UE5 and UE4. So I guess cleaning nvidia driver settings and reinstalling should fix it. You can define in your UE project settings to use DX11 (after starting with -dx11 or changing the default rhi in the ini file) but this will disable features like RayTracing.